# SyntaxError: unterminated string literal javascript console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am creating a Javasript object:

```
var obj= new Object();
obj.Message = $(".textarea").val();
```

and posting this object via JSON `stringify`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    url: 'xx/yy',
    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
    success: function (html) {
        // ...
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        // ...           
    }
});
```

I am getting:

> SyntaxError: unterminated string literal in console

What should I replace?

**EDIT:**

This issue is specific to data the user enters in plain text area (not rich text area)

Comment: You can click the error and it will lead you to the error source line.

Comment: this code does not seems to have any issue. is this all of your code ?

Comment: not your issue, but: `dataType: "json",` with `data: JSON.stringify(obj),` is wrong ... `dataType: "json", data:obj,` and you're golden

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply issue seems to be in data. I am using plan textarea for getting value user has input some character due to that its breaking.

Answer (score 1):

This may be your value of  have some line breaks or some invalid string literals. You can replaces line breaks of your textarea's value like this.

```
var str = $('#textarea1').val();
str = str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '');
```

This is full code snippet, so that u can check. Hopefully you can escape from "SyntaxError: unterminated string literal" when executing JSON.stringify(obj).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <textarea id="textarea1" rows="4" cols="50">
  </textarea>
  <input type="button" value="Check" id="btnCheck"/>
  
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
   
    $('#btnCheck').on('click',function(){
    
     var str = $('#textarea1').val();
     str = str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, ''); 
     var obj= new Object();
     obj.Message = str;
     
     console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
     
    });
   });
  </script>
 </body>
 
 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use template literals ``, which are supported in ECMAScript 2015 environments